# Trying to set nav bar to logged in, but entire nav bar is missing after creating function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set an if statement saying if the user is logged in, set a different nav bar. The issue I am running into is, the nav bar will not show up after putting it in a function and calling that function. When I take the code setting the nav bar to  out of the function, it brings up the nav bar.

also, I do understand that I shouldn't put user and pass into js, this is for a class and isn't actually going to be used.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="html-login">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../img/graphic-card.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Graphics Center</title>
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script defer src="../js/login-page.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Logo -->
  <img id="logo" src="../img/logo.png" alt="Graphics Center">
  <h1 id="tagline">We're like Toys R Us but for Graphics Cards enthusiasts!</h1>

<!-- Nav Bar made in JavaScript -->
  <nav></nav>

<!-- Login -->
  <article>
    <main id="main-holder">
      <h1 id="login-header">Login</h1>
      <div id="login-error-msg-holder">
        <p id="login-error-msg">Invalid username <span id="error-msg-second-line">and/or password</span></p>
      </div>

      <form id="login-form">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username-field" class="login-form-field" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password-field" class="login-form-field" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login-form-submit">
      </form>

    </main>
  </article>
</body>
<footer>
  <!-- Copyright info -->
  <p>Graphics Center © All rights reserved. </p>

  <!-- Time and date -->
  <p id="p1"></p>
  <script>var date = new Date();
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = date;</script>

  <!-- Link to gpu icon I used -->
  <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/gpu" title="gpu icons">Gpu icons created by smashingstocks - Flaticon</a>
  <script src="../js/nav.js"></script>
</footer>
</html>
```

Java Script

nav.js

```
//get the pathname from the current url
const path = window.location.pathname

const navBarNotLoggedIn= `
   <ul id="nav">
    <li class="navli"><a class="navA" href="../view/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navli"><a class="navA" href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li class="navli" style="float:right"><a class="navA" href="login.html">Login!</a></li>
   </ul>`

const navBarLoggedIn= `
   <ul id="nav">
    <li class="navli"><a class="navA" href="../view/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navli"><a class="navA" href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li class="navli" style="float:right"><a class="navA" href="#">Logged in!</a></li>
   </ul>`

function checkLogin() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("LoggedIn") == "true") {
        document.querySelector("nav").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", navBarLoggedIn);
    } else {
        document.querySelector("nav").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", navBarNotLoggedIn);
    }
}


document.load(checkLogin)

//For testing if nav bar works
//document.querySelector("nav").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", navBarNotLoggedIn);


//add the active class to the anchor tag with the href === path
document.querySelector(`[href='${path}']`).classList.add('active')
```

login-page.js

```
const loginForm = document.getElementById("login-form");
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login-form-submit");
const loginErrorMsg = document.getElementById("login-error-msg");
loginButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const username = loginForm.username.value;
    const password = loginForm.password.value;

    var LoggedIn = localStorage.setItem("LoggedIn", false);
    if (username === "user" && password === "web_dev") {
        alert(greetingResult);
        LoggedIn = true;
        location.reload();
    } else {
        loginErrorMsg.style.opacity = 1;
    }
})

const greetings = [
    "Welcome!"
    , "You've logged in!!"
    , "Jody sucks! but you've logged in!"
    , "Logging you out now...jk!"
    , "Pepsi sucks! but you've logged in"
    , "Welcome to Toy's R U- I mean Graphics Center!"
];
const greeting_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * greetings.length);
var greetingResult = greetings[greeting_id];
```

I tried throwing the nav bar in a function and an if statement to check if the user is logged in. When the user logs in, it sets the localStorage item "LoggedIn" to true. If true it shows "logged in" in the nav bar.

I haven't been able to test the if statement because the else statement isn't calling the nav bar. I tried not having a function and wrote an if statement in the variable but that still didn't work.

Comment: Are you calling the function `checkLogin()` anywhere?

Comment: Please give your question a more specific, descriptive title. 90% of questions are about finding out what they did wrong.

Comment: @SpencerMay yes, I tried it, I forgot to add it back to the code, I've edited it back cause it still produces the same issue

Comment: @Barmar My apologies, changed.

Answer (score 0):

You're never saving the LoggedIn = true back to localStorage

Also, setItem does NOT return the saved value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Comment: How do I fix that? also it still doesn't fix the else statment not calling "navBarNotLoggedIn" to <nav>

it works alone just not in the if-else statement

Comment: However you're determining that they are logged in, you will need to setItem('Logged in', true)

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I've changed it to "loggedIn = localStorage.setItem("LoggedIn", true);"

Comment: See the linked article, the return value of setItem is meaningless, so your local loggedin variable is meaningless.